# Callbacks to main thread without thread blocking (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a program which should managing threads (create, interrupt and show working threads). And I need to notify main thread about finishing, interruption or exceptions in worker thread. Main thread should react on this events, and of course it should not be blocked. As I know it behavior released in android in handler class. But I have no idea, how it possible to do in java. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I found good article about interaction with event dispatch thread:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/multi-threading-java-swing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an event loop in your main thread, you can have a queue which it polls to see if any new events it needs to process are waiting.  If you are using Swing or Android there will be an event loop already and a method you call to pass tasks to it.